# Anaconda Navigator Jupyter and Spyder won't start after successful installation

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, startup, anaconda3

I have installed Anaconda 3 on Windows 10 64-bit. The installation completed successfully. I could start idle.exe and it works. I can start the Anaconda Powershell and Anaconda Prompt, but I cannot start the Navigator nor Spyer or Jupyter. Launching them from the start menu will bring up the Windows shell windows for a moment, before they disappear and nothing happens.
I have tried starting the navigator from the Anaconda Prompt and this is what the error message looks like:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Frank> anaconda-navigator.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Frank\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Frank\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\Frank\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "C:\Users\Frank\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 37, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.analytics import GATracker
  File "C:\Users\Frank\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 44, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.external.UniversalAnalytics import Tracker
  File "C:\Users\Frank\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\external\UniversalAnalytics\Tracker.py", line 28, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import (HTTPSHandler, Request, build_opener,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'six.moves.urllib.request' (unknown location)
```

I have searched the internet for root causes of the last line in the error message with no success. There are a few tips how to fix it, but nothing worked.

The exact version I have installed is `Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe`.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda in all different "flavors":

1. for all users, without adding the path to the environment variables
2. for all users, with adding the path to the environment variables for
3. current user, without adding the path to the environment variables
4. for current user, with adding the path to the environment variables

Anaconda is installed into a directory without spaces in its name and no fancy characters: c:\users\frank\Anaconda3.

I have removed .anaconda and tried launching the navigator, spyer and jupyter again with no success.

Spyer comes up with a message that it had crashed during the last session. I followed the advice and deleted the .spyder-py3 folder, but no change.

How can I find more information about the reason for the problem on my system? Are there any log files that contain more information? I checked if HTTPSHandler is defined where Anaconda would search for it (please consider my limited expertise in Anaconda, when assuming where to look for resources...).

I installed the same Anaconda3 version on another computer and it works right from the start.

After reading another suggestion about updating conda using `conda update conda` and trying it on the Anaconda prompt I received the following error:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Frank> conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

I had the idea that SSL could be a problem and uninstalled OpenSSL v1.1.0g (Win64), then checked again. That doesn't help. Installing OpenSSL v1.1.0g (Win64) again doesn't make a difference either. On the other hand I would have assumed that Anaconda brings all components and modules it needs.

Any ideas how to continue troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept digging for answers and came across a discussion at GitHub:

[CondaHTTPError: Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available)](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6424#issuecomment-464660808)

I followed the advice, uninstalled my OpenSSL version and installed the latest one from the page https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. This is now "Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1d" and right after the installation all the issues with Anaconda were gone. I can use conda to update, the Anaconda Navigator comes up, Jupyter Notebook works. All is fine.