# jupyter notebook and spyder not launching from anaconda prompt.However it was working fine earlier. It is giving me the following error:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

> (base) C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3>jupyter notebook

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
    from notebook.notebookapp import main

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in 
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py", line 47, in 
    from zmq import backend

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 40, in 
    reraise(*exc_info)

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 27, in 
    _ns = select_backend(first)

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)

File "C:\Users\Aakash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

Answer (score 0):

Run these on anaconda prompt:

```
conda upgrade qt
```

OR

```
conda uninstall tornado
conda install tornado==6.0.4
```

OR

Check these previous answers 
[Anaconda Navigator Jupyter and Spyder won't start after successful installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578830/anaconda-navigator-jupyter-and-spyder-wont-start-after-successful-installation)

Comment: Tried using all the suggested ways but nothing worked.The error remains same.